# Gradle creating two Jar Files - i only want the "fat" one

Tags: java, gradle, shadow, fatjar, shadowjar

I've that gradle.build file:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ConfigureShadowRelocation
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

group = 'translator'
version = '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20230227'
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

task jar(overwrite: true, type: ShadowJar) {
    archiveName 'Translator.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task build(overwrite: true, type: ShadowJar) {
    archiveName 'Translator.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

tasks.register('relocateShadowJar', ConfigureShadowRelocation) {
    target = tasks.shadowJar
}

tasks.withType(ShadowJar).configureEach {
    dependsOn relocateShadowJar
    configurations = [
            project.configurations.shadow
    ]
    from {
        project.configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    dependencies {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.MF'
    }
}
```

any ideas why this creates everytime a "Translator.jar" file and a "Translator-1.0.jar" file?
I only want to have the "Translator.jar" file

I expect to only get the "Translator.jar" file in the build/libs folder

Comment: But why do you only need one jar file?  It looks a bit weird because you have set `project.version` in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: i need only that fat-jar...

Answer (score 0):

You have two tasks having the same configuration and performing the same action:

```
task jar(overwrite: true, type: ShadowJar) {
    archiveName 'Translator.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task build(overwrite: true, type: ShadowJar) {
    archiveName 'Translator.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Gradle will add a version number to the JAR file name to prevent overwriting the files. To avoid that, make these files have distinct `archiveName` or remove one of them as they're doing the same thing.

Comment: Nope, when using 
`archiveName 'Translator2.jar'` and `archiveName 'Translator.jar'` it still makes two files - "Translator.jar" and "Translator-1.0.jar"...
Same happens when I remove the task jar.
i use gradlew.bat build

Comment: @Anonymous have you used `./gradlew clean` before building again?

Comment: yes i used it, I also used ./gradlew clean build (i tested both)

Comment: @Anonymous try to set `archiveName = 'Translator.jar'` inside `configureEach{}`, after `afterconfigurations = [project.configurations.shadow]` while deleting both these tasks

Comment: Nope, same problem